# How can I use a single value from my array property from my model in Angular 16?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a very simple typescript class:

```
export class DayOffer {
  private id: number;
  private day: string;
  private offers: string[];


  constructor(id: number, day: string, offers:string[]) {
    this.id = id;
    this.day = day;
    this.offers = offers;
  }
}
```

And I would like to use a single, specific value from my class:

```
 offers: DayOffer[] = [
    new DayOffer(1, "Maandag", ["Stoofvlees"]),
    new DayOffer(2, "Dinsdag", ["Hamburgers","Gehakt"]),
    new DayOffer(4, "Donderdag", ["Stoofvlees","Gehakt"]),
    new DayOffer(5, "Vrijdag", ["Hamburgers","Kotelettengebraad"]),
    new DayOffer(6, "Zaterdag", ["Schnitzels","Kotelettengebraad"]),
  ];
```

But I can only call the full array and not 1 specific value from the "offers" Array.
this is how I'm able to call the full array:

```
<div class="pb-5"><strong>{{offer["offers"]}}</strong></div>
```

I've tried calling it just by adding an index {{offer["offers[1]"] but this doesnt work.

Comment: `offer["offers"][1]` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-contaner *ngIf="offer && offer.offers">
  <ng-contaner *ngFor="let offerItem of offer.offers">
    <div class="pb-5"><strong>{{ offerItem }}</strong></div>
  </ng-contaner>
</ng-contaner>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your class to

```
export class DayOffer {
  id: number;
  day: string;
  offers: string[];

  constructor(id: number, day: string, offers:string[]) {
    this.id = id;
    this.day = day;
    this.offers = offers;
  }
}
```

And try with this in your html component or view

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let dayOffer of dayOffers;trackBy:trackByDayOffer">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let offer of dayOffer.offers;let index = index;trackBy:trackByOffer">
        <div class="pb-5">
            <strong>
                {{ dayOffer.id }}.{{ index }} {{ offer }}
            </strong>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Modify ts file with this

```
  dayOffers = [
    new DayOffer(1, "Maandag", ["Stoofvlees"]),
    new DayOffer(2, "Dinsdag", ["Hamburgers","Gehakt"]),
    new DayOffer(4, "Donderdag", ["Stoofvlees","Gehakt"]),
    new DayOffer(5, "Vrijdag", ["Hamburgers","Kotelettengebraad"]),
    new DayOffer(6, "Zaterdag", ["Schnitzels","Kotelettengebraad"]),
  ];

  trackByOffer(_: number, item: string): string{
    return item;
  }

  trackByDayOffer(_: number, item: DayOffer): number{
    return item.id;
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35084458)